# WebUIDelegate methods not called

Tags: cocoa, webview, delegates, webkit

For some reason the following webview UI delegate methods are never called. Tried opening, clicking, interacting with webview to trigger the delegate calls and nothing works.

```
- (void)webViewFocus:(WebView *)sender {
    NSLog(@"focusing %@", sender);
}

- (void)webViewUnfocus:(WebView *)sender {
    NSLog(@"unfocusing %@", sender);
}

- (BOOL)webViewIsStatusBarVisible:(WebView *)sender {
    return YES;
}

- (void)webView:(WebView *)sender setStatusBarVisible:(BOOL)visible {
    NSLog(@"%@  %d", sender, visible);
}
```

I made sure the the delegate is correctly hooked up and can confirm that when user wants to open a new window, `- (WebView *)webView:(WebView *)sender createWebViewWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request` WebUIDelegate method is correctly called. Any ideas?

Comment: Nope, ended up not depending on the delegate at all. If you find a solution let me know.

Comment: runOpenPanelForFileButtonWithResultListener this methode not called when i click input file button . i have connected uidelegate in interface builder itself

Comment: - (WebView *)webView:(WebView *)sender createWebViewWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request:
This method can let my WebView instance open links in itself. But the others WebUIDelegate do not work at all. Is there someone can explain it?